# Ubiquity Unifi wont accept login after migration

Tags: migration, ubiquiti

I've migrated a existing Unifi Controller to another server. When the configuration Wizard appeard, I choose "Restore from Backup" after the Import the login screen appears, but the Login isn't working.

I tried these versions
`5.5.24 -> 5.5.24` and 
`5.5.24 -> 5.6.26`

Any Ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was I made the wrong backup. I made the Backup at `Settings-> Site -> Export Site` which seems to be insufficient. I read that on a Migration how-to.

`Settings -> Maintenance -> Backup` is the right backup to take.

Comment: What an awful design. Export Site workflow is the one for migrating to a new controller.